# Team development Sitecore postscript

Tags: sitecore, tds

I am using `Team development Sitecore` for creating `sitecore package` `.update` file.

I want to call my own `dll` in `sc_poststep.txt`, `IS TDS` has the option to include our `dll` in `sc_poststep.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there isn't a way to do this with TDS.

Your best option is to create a page that can be called after the update file has been installed and then either call this via a build task or manually.

We have added this feature to the TDS backlog.